# Typescript mixins with default property values (derived from new MyClass)

Tags: typescript, mixins

I am experimenting with some mixins in Typescript and have got the basics working with a few different methods of building the mixin. In all of them I am getting the same error.

This is my mixin class:

```
export class OnDestroyMixin implements OnDestroy {

    public destroyStream: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        console.log(`on destroy from mixin`);

        this.destroyStream.next();
        this.destroyStream.complete();
    }
}
```

and whenever the on destroy function is called (after this has been mixed into another class) the `this.destroyStream` does not exist so I get a `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined` error.

I have considered setting this up in a constructor but I am not sure how constructors work in mixins either...

I assume that this should be possible.

The mixin method I am currently using is a mixin decorator:

```
export function Mixin(baseCtors: Function[]) {
    return function (derivedCtor: Function) {
        baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
                const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name);

                if (name === 'constructor')
                    return;

                if (descriptor && (!descriptor.writable || !descriptor.configurable || !descriptor.enumerable || descriptor.get || descriptor.set)) {
                    Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, descriptor);
                } else {
                    derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
                }

            });
        });
    };
}
```

Which I copied from somewhere online but as I have said I've tried a few different methods that all essentially copy properties from one prototype to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is that when you define a property value on a class when this is transpiled to JavaScript [this value is set in the constructor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20MyProperty%20%3D%20%22value%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A). The mixin code above specifically ignores the constructor. The real solution here is to merge the 2 class constructors together.

There seem to be 2 different approaches to mixins in Typescript. Approaches similar to the one in my question where we iterate through the prototype properties and copy them from one class to another and another where we simply [return a new class that extends the original](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/typescript-mixins-part-two/):

```
function Flies<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        fly() {
            alert('Is it a bird? Is it a plane?');
        }
    };
}
```

I had thought that I wouldn't be able to use this in angular as it's a function that returns a new class but it is perfectly possible as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/Roaders/angular-automatic-unsubscribe/blob/91aa019b8b0946e0288c2901f1d25a7f537e83fa/example/app/sample-child/sample-child.component.ts):

```
class SourceClass{}

@Component({
    selector: 'some-selector',
    templateUrl: './some-selector.html',
    styleUrls: ['./some-selector.scss']
})
export class SampleMixedClass extends Flies(SourceClass) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my previous answer the issue is that the value of the property is set in the constructor of the mixin class and the constructor is ignored in the mixin decorator.

Another way around this is to not set the property value in the constructor but instead to define the property with a getter and a setter:

```
export class OnDestroyMixin implements OnDestroy {
    private _destroyStream: Subject<boolean>;

    public get destroyStream(): Subject<boolean>{
        let stream = this._destroyStream;

        if(stream == null){
            stream = new Subject<boolean>();
            this._destroyStream = stream;
        }

        return stream;
    }


    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroyStream.next();
        this.destroyStream.complete();
    }
}
```

In fact in this case a setter is not needed as a read only value is helpful. As we are using a getter this is not a normal property and is not set in the constructor. Rather we define a property with a getter function. This is copied across in the mixin decorator.